# How precise are iPhone 4 compass API readings?

Tags: iphone, compass-geolocation

I'd like to develop an iPhone 4 app that uses the compass API, but I need readings at least as precise as a half a degree (eg. 100.5).

What kind of precision does the compass API provide?

Comment: FYI, there's a difference between [accuracy and precision](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Accuracy_and_precision) that might be worth knowing if you are going to do further research on the matter.

Answer (score 1):

In my experience, not anywhere near that.

Answer (score 0):

According to [this site](http://www.wyrdy.com/news/2009/05/22/where-is-the-iphone-compass-pointing/), the accuracy is supposed to be within 1.4 degrees. As with any magnetic compass, interference from surrounding objects and electronics will have some impact as well.

Answer (score 0):

You have to tilt compensate the compass first, so the accurary of accelerometer matters too.

After a sophisticated calibration of both the compass and the accelerometer, it is nowhere near that on the [Shimmer2r](http://www.shimmer-research.com/products-2) platform.

I would expect the iPhone compass to be worse, especially without calibration.

Answer (score 0):

You can use de Giroscope + Compass to get a bigger precision.